# Drag and drop a html file to C# form

Tags: c#, html, drag-and-drop

I was wondering if there is a way to drag and drop a html file to a C# form and keep the formatting. I can drag a html file and have it create a link in a rich textbox, but that's not what I need. Ideally I'm trying to make it so I can drag a webpage into some sort of textbox in a C# application, so I can parse the information and sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use web browser control , here is the link :

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx
```

There is an example :

```
string html  = "<html><body>hi</body></html>";
webBrowser.DocumentText = html;
```

In drag drop event , you should catch the filename and it contents and then you can display those on the webBrowser Control.

Answer (score 0):

When you use drag and drop like you said you have file name.  What you can do is to open that html file take file content and place it in you textbox.

In case if your html file is some web page you can get content of it by:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
myTextBox.Text = webClient.DownloadString("YourHTMLFilePath");
```